# how to convert image data to float32?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I'm trying to convert image to float32 in order to use it in tensorflow model, the conversion method I am using is;

```
    Uint8List imageToByteListFloat32(
    img.Image image, int inputSize, double mean, double std) {
  var convertedBytes = Float32List(1 * inputSize * inputSize * 3);
  var buffer = Float32List.view(convertedBytes.buffer);
  int pixelIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputSize; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < inputSize; j++) {
      var pixel = image.getPixel(j, i);
      buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getRed(pixel) - mean) / std;
      buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getGreen(pixel) - mean) / std;
      buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getBlue(pixel) - mean) / std;
    }
  }
  print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> uint8${convertedBytes.buffer.asUint8List()}');
  print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>${convertedBytes.buffer.asFloat32List()}');
  return convertedBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
}
```

**I have found this method from [github/shaqian](https://github.com/shaqian/flutter_tflite), but it is not working for me, and whenever I try to run this method it just give me this error.**

```
I/CameraManagerGlobal( 8308): Connecting to camera service
E/flutter ( 8308): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: /data/user/0/com.example.model_ui/cache/image_picker5737695500402504399.jpg
E/flutter ( 8308): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:237:7)
E/flutter ( 8308): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8308): #1      _SelectImageState.pickGallery (package:model_ui/main/select_image.dart:63:23)
E/flutter ( 8308): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8308):
```

and this is how I give it a image from flutter side;

```
      pickImage() async {
    var image = await imagePicker!.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (image == null) return null;
    var imageBytes = (await rootBundle.load(image.path)).buffer;
    print('imageBytes: ${imageBytes}');
    image_lib.Image? oriImage = image_lib.decodeJpg(imageBytes.asUint8List());
    print('oriImage: ${oriImage}');
    image_lib.Image resizedImage = image_lib.copyResize(oriImage!, height: 224, width: 224);
    print('resizedImage: ${resizedImage}');
    imageToByteListFloat32(resizedImage, 224, 127.5, 127.5);
  }
```

Comment: It looks like the exception is from the Bundle and nothing to do with byte data. Based on the exception it looks like `await rootBundle.load(image.path)` is blowing up. `rootBundle` is typically an AssetBundle meant for loading assets packaged with your app... not for loading images from an image picker.

Comment: so, what should I do for loading images from an image picker?

Comment: I would suggest reading the documentation. If you're using the `image_picker` package, it looks like `pickImage` returns and `XFile` object which has a `readAsBytes` method which yields a `Future<Uint8List>` which should get you what you want.

Comment: Not related to the question, but shouldn't the return type of this method be Float32List instead of Uint8List as suggested by the name?